# Return values of dictionary except for a given key

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have what seems like a very simple problem, but for some reason it's not working and I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have a dictionary, with a numeric key and a class object as the value. I want to enter a key and return all values for the dictionary except the value for the specified key.

The example below return nothing.

```cs
static readonly Dictionary<int, LinkDto> _chips = new Dictionary<int, LinkDto>()
{
    { 100, new LinkDto("url1", "text1") },
    { 200, new LinkDto("url2", "text2") },
    { 500, new LinkDto("url3", "text3") },
    { 1000, new LinkDto("url4", "text4") },
    { 1500, new LinkDto("url5", "text5") },
};
```

This is the method that interrogates the dictionary:

```cs
public void Build(int key)
{
    Build(_chips
        .Where(x => !_chips.ContainsKey(key))
        .Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
}
```

And this is the call:

```cs
    Build(1500);
```

I expect it to return the values for 100, 200, 500 and 1000.

Comment: What is the other `Build` method that accepts a List parameter?

Comment: I think you need to replace `.Where(x => !_chips.ContainsKey(key))` with `.Where(x => x.Key != key)`.

Comment: @AstridE. You're absolutely right, that produced the right result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```csharp
_chips.Where(x => !_chips.ContainsKey(key))
```

will return *no* entries in `_chips` in the case where `_chips` *does* contain an entry with a key equal to `key`.
It will return *all* entries in the case where `_chips` contains *no* entry with a key equal to `key`.

Considering your example dictionary (containing keys **100, 200, 500, 1000, 1500**) and example `key` value of **1500**, the filtering operation actually is:

```csharp
_chips.Where(x => !_chips.ContainsKey(1500))
```

The `!_chips.ContainsKey(1500)` part never changes for any of the dictionary entries (`x`), and will therefore have the same value when performing the filtering for all entries; regardless of the entry's `Key` value.

I am quite sure that you want to replace the `.Where()` expression with something like:

```csharp
.Where(x => x.Key != key)
```

to filter out the entry whose `Key` equals the provided `key` value.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TValue> GetOtherValues<TKey,TValue>( this IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue> dict, TKey notThisKey )
    where TKey : notnull, IEquatable<TKey>
{
    if( dict is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dict));

    return dict.Where( kvp => !notThisKey.Equals( kvp.Key ) ).Select( kvp => kvp.Value );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extension method, I'll store that.